# In jmeter, while using CSV Data Set Config for webservice method getting error

Tags: jmeter

I am using `Jmeter` (Run as administrator) in order to load and test a webservice method using some CSV Data Set Config. 
I have the CSV file under the `jmeter` folder with path:

```
 "D:\ROHINI DATA\Softwares\Jmeter\Setup\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples.
```

On the given path the jmx and csv files are present. This is true also while the script is executing and it's displaying an error as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9B9s.png):
 [image: screenshot]:

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Add full path of file in place of filename (string.csv) and then try.

Comment: Can you list out the files in your examples directory?

Comment: Hey friends, thanks for reply...  Issue is resolved....

Comment: @Rohini what was it?

Comment: @RichardFriedman....There was issue in file extension. While creating csv file, my file extension was hidden so once I unhide it my file name was string.csv.txt.... :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be connected with the space between `ROHINI` and  `DATA`

Try the following workarounds:

1. Double check that file `D:\ROHINI DATA\Softwares\Jmeter\Setup\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\examples\string.csv` exists
2. If the file exists - provide full path in the "Filename" section
3. There is [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function which offers similar functionality, you can try switching to it.

See [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) guide for more details on proper configuration.